# How can I get the requirements.txt file on Colab or Kaggle notebook?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kaggle, requirements.txt

I finished my project on Kaggle but I want to add requirements file how can I do it

I want to do it directly from Kaggle or colab file

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/getting-started/396739)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Google colab**, to get an initial colab environment (set of modules that already installed by Google colab. You can use it without any further import) , you can try this :

```
# to get packages initially installed in colab or in other word, the colab environment
!pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

For the code above, the requirements.txt file will appear in the content section of your Google colab (will be in the path named : ‘**/content/**‘)
Or, in case that what you want is the imported module, not a colab environment. What you can do is :

```
# get list of all imported modules 
import sys
print(sys.modules.keys())
```

Moreover, for the **requirements.txt** in kaggle, you can take a quick look at the comment below your question section. The reference link provided by **Ali Ent** was very clear

Hope this help !